# Eloquent Relationships and Fetching Data with Constraints

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm experimenting with implementing a forum with just one database table; called `discussions_posts`. Here's the structure -

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('child_of')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('category_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->mediumText('body')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('active');
        $table->unsignedInteger('last_reply_by')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

A thread always starts with post with `child_of` set to `null` and is followed by all the subsequent posts where `child_of` is equal to the `id` of the first post.

The problem is when rendering the thread index; which needs to show all the 'threads' that are sorted by when they were updated (aka the timestamp of the last post) in the thread.

I tried this with following -

```
Post::latest()->get();
```

This will fetch all the `posts` (irrespective of whether they are first posts or a post that are child of any main post).

I want to show the following information on the thread index -

1. Title of the thread (for which I will need to find out the first post in the series)
2. Person who posted the last reply. I need to extract their user avatar and name.

Would really appreciate if someone could show me a way to do this.

Comment: This would create large performance issues very quickly. I would strongly suggest implementing anoth table threads, where you can show the title and last reply, as well as a pivot table which links all posts belong to a thread together, so that you can get them all in one query.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Decided to drop the idea.